# Should hand-coded stubs be unit-tested?

Tags: unit-testing, language-agnostic

In an environment where the use of a mocking framework is not an option, should hand-coded stubs and fakes (etc.) themselves be unit-tested?

For example, imagine I have a fake logger class that logs to memory rather than to file. The fake is extremely simple – it just keeps a record of log messages – but as it is hand-coded should it still be unit-tested?

Comment: Can you explain more your trouble ?

Comment: It's not really a problem but more a question about whether or not unit-testing hand-coded fakes is worthwhile/recommended/good-practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no need to separately test them. Your unit tests and tested code act as tests *for each other*.

If you are using Test Driven Development (TDD), the red phase of the red-green-refactor cycle also tests your stubs.

Answer (score 0):

Globally for me, any not tested code is a future-dead. So I advise you to test usage of any part of all written code. And in test driven development philosophy, you'll be sure after any changement that this part of code will be right.

In Python, I test unittest utilities with doctests instead of real unittest.

It allows me to split application tests and test utilities tests. And give developers concret help in docstring.

[Doctest official doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one of those scenarios where, annoyingly, it depends. Typically I do not write tests for  hand rolled stubs, and would 100% agree with the point @Raedwald makes that unit tests and stubs should essentially act as tests for each other. However there have been certain situations where it felt correct to do so, for example:

- When there is any kind of conditional logic involved that tests rely upon (e.g. the stub calculates output based on the input provided), then it can be useful to verify this separately. I'm not saying that putting conditional logic in stubs is a good testing practice mind you, but can be useful in some scenarios.
- When the stubs are being used for larger scale integration tests, because in this environment determining the root cause of a test failure can be much more difficult, and it is particularly frustrating if the root cause turns out to be a poorly coded stub.

In summary, I don't think it's a bad practice to unit test them if your gut tells you it's a good idea, however it's certainly not the end of the world if you don't bother either. I wouldn't sweat the decision too much.